# infinite OAuth Redirect Loop with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to OAuth users of my single-page webapp but I'm ending with infinite redirects there.

I registered application in express to behave like when url is hit, then redirect user to OAuth server:

```
expressApp.use("/", (req, res) => {
    var redirectUri = "http://myApp.com";
    var clientId = "someClientID";
    var redir = "https://someOAuth.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" + clientId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri;
    res.status(301).redirect(redir);
});
```

But as you all expect, when OAuth server redirects user back into application, server is taking him back to OAuth server and again and again.

Then I tried to set `redirecUri` variable to `"http://myApp.com/login/callback"` and register another path like following:

```
expressApp.use("/login/callback", (req, res) => {
    var redir = "http://myApp.com";
    res.status(301).redirect(redir);
});
```

Did not help as well.

Could you anybody help me there explaining how to handle redirect back from OAuth to my webapp correctly, please?

Comment: What is your resource server? An app you wrote? Did u write also the oauth server?

Comment: I'm using successfactors SAMLOAuth server and backend + frontend part of an app is mine.

Comment: just to make sure - your redirect-back URL is open in the client app?

Comment: exactly, all redirects mentioned in question redirect client..